# Нужна ли запятая перед "который"?

Tags: запятые, союзы, вводные-слова

*Она встретила человека, как выяснялось(,) который спас ей жизнь*

Нужна ли запятая перед "который"? Или же вводное слово стоит тут в начале обособленного оборота, и запятая не нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректная запись: *Она встретила человека, **который (как потом выяснилось)** спас ей жизнь.*

1. Существуют определенные **нормы построения придаточных определительных предложений**, поэтому нет оснований для размещения вводного слова между главной и придаточной частями.
2. Лучше использовать форму "**как потом выяснилось**", если это возможно по тексту.